# Filtering search results from Scopus API using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scopus

I have made an API key from Elsevier and I'm using Python to access the Scopus API to fetch records for physics papers in the UK via the following:

```
import requests
import json
from myscopus import MYAPIKEY

URL = "http://api.elsevier.com/content/search/scopus?query=\
      "AFFIL%28university+AND+physics+AND+united+kingdom%29+\
      "AND+SUBJAREA%28PHYS%29&field=affiliation"
header = {'Accept' : 'application/json', 
          'X-ELS-APIKey' : MYAPIKEY}
resp = requests.get(URL, headers=header)

results = resp.json()

print([[str(r['affiliation'])] for r in results['search-results']["entry"]])
```

I only want results which are PURELY affiliated with the UK (i.e. no authors can be from elsewhere). If I run the search manually on Scopus, I can do this by refining the results, excluding results for every other country other than the united kingdom. Is there a way I can do this in Python without loads of lines of code?

To do this manually on the site I had to select roughly 30-40 boxes for the country and then click 'exclude' which was rather time consuming: [image: The refined Scopus search]

Comment: Could you provide us with a sample of the JSON?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/56akj70jvtdxxna/AAAHXxAG0WaVUGtZdhEDfRIga?dl=0